# The best way to copy repeating n number of byte in string array in vb

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net

I have a string of data (20 bytes) for example [00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 A0 AA BB B0 B1 B0]

What is the best practical way to copy every four bytes using array.copy?

is there any other quicker and simpler way?

My end result will be something like below:

```
Dim A(3) As String = [00 01 02 03]
Dim A1(3) As String = [04 05 06 07]
.
.
Dim A4(3) As String = [BB B0 B1 B0]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you give some more detail/background? I'm not understanding the reason behind this so it's hard to know how to help

Answer (score 1):

Best?  Up for debate.  Here's one approach:

[String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) is your friend.
Also, I recommend the overload of [Array.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_) where you can choose the sourceIndex.

```
    Dim theString As String = "00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 A0 AA BB B0 B1 B0"

    Dim fullArray As String() = theString.Split(" ")

    Dim A(3), A1(3), A2(3) As String

    Array.Copy(fullArray, 0, A, 0, 4)
    Array.Copy(fullArray, 4, A1, 0, 4)
    Array.Copy(fullArray, 8, A2, 0, 4)
```

But I echo @Marcucciboy2: More background is helpful for what you want to do. It's not obvious from your question if the string of data is really a string; I inferred it from the arrays you built, but I could be wrong.  Being as complete as possible with sample code is helpful, so we can see the full context.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for not being so clear about it. But @sean, the one you did using array.copy is exactly i'm looking for. But, if you have hundreds of bytes, you don't want to write array.copy everytime. Is there anyway that we could shorten the line of code here?